# How to extract Facebook Recommendations Box data using FQL or php sdk?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-fql, fbml

I need the data being displayed in the Facebook Recommendations Box, either using FQL or the php-sdk.

The Facebook Recommendations Box gives me a random number of recommended URLs, and I need it to be sorted.

For example:

If I give one URL ([www.example.com](http://www.example.com)) to Facebook Recommendations Box, then it will show me the most recommended pages (URLs) of the site. However, it will display these results with the recommended count randomly. I need that data to be sorted with most recommend URL to show first.

> [www.example.com/page1.html](http://www.example.com/page1.html) (2,203 people recommend this.)
>
> [www.example.com/page2.html](http://www.example.com/page2.html) (795 people recommend this.)
>
> [www.example.com/page3.html](http://www.example.com/page3.html) (1,203 people recommend this.)

Also, this plugin has box and borders etc. I just need the URL and figure.

Is it possible do do this through FQL or php-sdk?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fql query to get the data. The fql query will be like :

```
SELECT url, share_count, like_count, comment_count, total_count
FROM link_stat WHERE url="www.example.com/page1.html"
```

and you can get the data by url encoding the query and sending it to

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?format=xml&query="SELECT url, share_count,..."
```

Now you will receive the

```
<share_count>1</share_count>
<like_count>3</like_count>
<comment_count>4</comment_count>
<total_count>8</total_count>
```

now you can store the values for each urls in an array and then sort it.

For more info regarding the stats, check this [link](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat/)

Comment: Hello Ram, Thanks for the answer. But I don't want this way by giving individual urls(I have 30000 diffent urls), instead I need to give just domain name and Recommendations Box will fetch the urls and recommended figure. I want the FQL or php-sdk that will fetch all data related to different urls & figure of recommendation. In short, I want same output, which gives Recommendations Box. BUT in my way not through plugin.